# Can I say "pain is relieved" or "soreness is relieved"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice

I am emailing a professor and I wonder if the saying "has your tooth soreness been relieved a bit" or "has your toothache been relieved a bit" is the correct saying. Is the passive voice a correct usage? And is "relieve" a good word for usage?

Comment: You sentences are both idiomatic English, but the best is _"Has your toothache been relieved a bit?"_ The passive voice is fine here, and the verb _to relieve_ is a good choice. Welcome to ELL. Please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. we hope you will ask more questions!

Comment: It is good to go. Another option would be alleviate.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your choices

> Has your tooth soreness been relieved a bit?
>   Has your toothache been relieved a bit?

are understandable and quite deferential, usually an ache related to one's teeth is called a

> **toothache**

not a "**soreness**".  Other ways to express ask the same question are

> Has the pain in your tooth stopped?
>   Has your toothache stopped?
>   Is your toothache better?

Answer (score 1):

"Relieve" implies that there is a specific agent that cause your discomfort to recede.

"Did the aspirin relieve your soreness?"

Using in the passive voice suggests that you don't know what the cause is -- but using the word "relieve" suggests that you think there was a cause.  It's hard to see what circumstances would justify both those suggestions at once.

If you are asking merely in the vague hope that the problem has lessened, because of some treatment or simply the passage of time, you should "Is your toothache still bothering you?"